# Как возобновить activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

Есть первое активити, mainActivity, есть второе активити, который запускается через Intent, как мне проверить второе активити, на то что он уже есть в стеке, если есть то запустить, если его нет, то создать новый.

Comment: а зачем проверять? если mainActivity в foreground значит что вторая явно не в стеке

Comment: если вам нужен шаг вперед по иерархии - вызывайте через интент следующюю, если шаг назад - вызывайте finish() в текущей (нажатие системеной кнопки "назад" выполнит это автоматически), не надо ничего мудрить, тем более, что вы не имеете никаких возможностей "запустить" или "создать новый" - что это вообще значит в вашем понимании?

Comment: Объясняю: в первом активити есть лист, по нажатию которой, появляется второе активити, где редактирую и нажимаю на кнопку сохранить, после создается снова первое активити. Первое активити - это не MainActivity. Это же второе активити я использую для создания записей, который загружаются в лист первого актиивити. Так вот, если несколько раз буду нажимать на лист и сохранять, то несклько раз и создается активити. Можно поставить финишь, то тогда перейдет в mainactivity, что также неприемлемо, нужно переходить в активити с лист.

Comment: Ничего мудрить не нужно. Закрываете активити-редактор финишем или кнопкой "назад" и программа возвращается в активити-список.

Comment: @АнтонЛялин после нажатия на кнопку сохранить не надо создавать заново первое активити, достаточно закрыть второе, а в первом для адаптера списка вызвать notifyItemChanged();

Comment: почему вы думаете, что перейдете по finish() в MainActivity, если вы вызываете вторую из первой? во второй делаете finish() и попадаете в первую. Уточнения к вопросу нужно писать в сам вопрос (кнопка "править" под вопросом), а не в комментарии к нему

Comment: Запускаете activity, в котором вы будете создавать запись, с помощью команды startActivityForResult(). Создаете запись и завершете его с помощью setResult(RESULT_OK, intent); finish();  После завершения будет отправлен результат. Необходимо будет переопределить метод onActivityResult(...), в котором будете "отлавливать" результат и описываете дальнейшую логику работы.(Пример: http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/68-urok-29-vyzyvaem-activity-i-poluchaem-rezultat-metod-startactivityforresult.html)